# Evaluate $\int_3^9 \frac{1}{x \log x} \,\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_3^9 \frac{1}{x \log x} \,\mathrm dx$$

I tried :

$$u=\log x \implies x \ln 10 du = dx$$

$$\ln 10 \int_{\log 3}^{2\log 3} \frac{1}{u} du = \ln 10 \left[\ln u \right]_{\log 3}^{2\log 3}=\ln 10 \left[\ln(2 \ln 3)-\ln(\ln 3) \right]=$$

$$\ln 10 \left[\ln\frac{2 \ln 3}{(\ln 3)} \right]=\ln 10 \cdot \ln 2$$

But this isn't correct, why?

Comment: How do you know that it is not correct? Do you know the solution? What is it?

Comment: @ajotatxe This is an assignment, the computer only tells I'm wrong, it doesn't give an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is correct, because you have interpreted $\log x$ as $\log_{10} x$. Unfortunately, in some texts $\log x$ denotes the natural logarithm as well, namely $\log_e x$, or $\ln x$.

If that's the case, the solution is much simpler and it is obtained in the same way as you did.

$$\int_3^9 \frac 1{x\ln x}\mathrm dx = \left[\begin{align}u = \ln x\\x\mathrm du = \mathrm dx\end{align}\right] = \int_{\ln 3}^{2\ln 3}\frac 1u\mathrm du = \ln 2$$

Comment: @M.S.E: No problem, I'm glad I could be of help!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that all are natural logarithms, consider $$I=\int\frac{dx}{x \log x} $$ and, as you did, change variable $x=e^y$. So $$I=\int\frac{dy}{y}= \log (y)=\log\Big(\log(x)\Big) $$Now, use the bounds.

Comment: @M.S.E. You are very welcome !